# How To filter div element based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter the div element based on user input i already done with table element but now i need to do the same in div element.

**User Input**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Teacher.." title="Type in a name"><br/>
```

**Table data**

```
<div style="border:1px solid gray">

<table id="myTable" >
    <c:forEach var="tr" items="${teachersList}">

    <tr><td><a href="teacher_view_adm?tcrId=${tr.id}" >${tr.fname} ${tr.lname}</a><br/>Last Seen</td>

    </tr>

    </c:forEach>

    </table>
</div>
```

**Table script**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  if(filter==""){

      }

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }

}
</script>
```

above code works fine for table elements but how can i change to div elements. bellow i specify the structure of div element data.

**Div element**

```
 <div style="border:1px solid gray" id="myDiv">


        <c:forEach var="tr" items="${teachersList}">
    <div>
        <p><a href="teacher_view_adm?tcrId=${tr.id}" >${tr.fname} ${tr.lname}</a><br/>Last Seen</p>


    </div>
        </c:forEach>

            </div>
```

I need to change the above **table script** to **div element script** can any one help me to do this?

Comment: You want to *sort* or *filter* divs?

Comment: @Rajesh i need to filter div

Comment: And can this have nested divs?

Comment: @Rajesh yes every element are placed in separate divs in for each loop and it have master div

Comment: No Jquery here, can you use?

Comment: you can look for querySelectorAll, e.g. document.getElementById("id").querySelectorAll("div");

Comment: @AnilKumar i tried with javascript . can you tell how to achieve this using jquery

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need something like this.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();

  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    if (a) {
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        divs[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for Teacher.." title="Type in a name"><br/>
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <p><a href="">test data 1</a><br/>Last Seen</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a href="">test data 2</a><br/>Last Seen</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a href="">new test data 3</a><br/>Last Seen</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npx0gv9n/

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done without any js framework

```js
function getValue(val){  
     //search goes here 
     document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
       if(item.textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith(val.toLowerCase())) {
         item.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
         item.style.display = 'none';
       }
     });
}
```

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Please type.." onkeyup="getValue(this.value)">
 
<div id="result">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">HXML</li>
    <li class="item">CPP</li>
    <li class="item">FHF</li>
    <li class="item">Coffeescript</li>
    <li class="item">Tart</li>
    <li class="item">Cython</li>
    <li class="item">Swift</li>
    <li class="item">Gava</li>
    <li class="item">C++</li>
    <li class="item">GoKart</li>
    <li class="item">SCSS</li>
    <li class="item">C</li>
    <li class="item">LASS</li>
    <li class="item">Pearl</li>
    <li class="item">Rooby</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea

- Get the parent `div` and check if it has `div`s inside it.
- If yes, use recursion to validate them.
- If not, validate them directly.
- To validate, accept `searchQuery` and `div`'s text and parse them to lowercase. This will allow you to do case insensitive search.
- Them just check for existence of `searchQuery` in this text. If yes, add a class (`hide`). If no, remove it.

```js
function searchMyValue(container) {
  var search = document.getElementById('txtQuery').value.toLowerCase();
  var text = container.textContent.toLowerCase();
  var childDivs = container.querySelectorAll('div');
  if (childDivs.length) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(childDivs).forEach(x => searchMyValue(x));
  } else if (search.trim() && text.indexOf(search) < 0) {
    container.classList.add('hide')
  } else {
    container.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btnSearch')
btn.addEventListener("click", searchMyValue.bind(btn, document.querySelector('.container')))

function createDivs(array, element) {
  var divs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var d = document.createElement('div');
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.textContent = array[i];
      p.append(a);
      d.append(p);
      divs.push(d);
    })(i)
  }
  element.append.apply(element, divs)
}

createDivs(["foo", "bar", "Hello World", "test"], document.querySelector('.content'));
createDivs(["Sachin", "Rahul", "Trend", "Virat"], document.querySelector('.content2'));
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <input type="text" id="txtQuery">
  <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```